# Down vote in Meta - 2 years after being closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, down-votes

**For clarification -- this is NOT a SUGGESTION TO CHANGE question - it's just a operational process question**

I'm just curious if this issue is a bug or intentional behavior, and if intentional behavior what purpose it serves?

Back around February, 2014 I posted a view on the up/down vote system directed at Stack Overflow. I wasn't supportive of it for my own reasons. The question had a lot of debate back and forth but was downvoted  heavily -- so be it, we all moved on.

Strangely though, I logged in today to find a -2 reputation because the question got a recent downvote (after being closed and almost 2 years old). Now here is my question:

The Question is **closed** since February, 2014 and already marked heavily with downvotes, is that a correct behavior of the Stack Exchange back end? Shouldn't this thing be dead by now and cleaned up as junk? Or at least since it's closed, should it still be allowing up/down votes?

Comment: I could be called bored for trying to find people on meta and help them if I can, but please know that voting on meta is different and the downvoter says "I disagree with what you say". So, *you* tell me why they shouldn't be able to say this when the post gets closed or is old or is new.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. - firstly - I didn't say they can't, I asked if it was an intentional feature or a bug. I was a query about the StackExchange process. Secondly - Down voting THIS question using your words "I disagree with what you say"..... I offered no statement of fact to "disagree" with, it was a question. What exactly would the downvoters be disagreeing with here? The fact that a question was even asked?

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree with the idea that old and closed questions should be protected from downvotes. Or, if you did not intend to suggest this, because you did not bother to check how things work. This is trivial part of the whole voting process.

Comment: @ShadowWizard **almost** every question asked in the StackExchange system already has 1 to hundreds of answers already on the web if someone "bothered to check", either minimally or at length. Some people have lots of free time for this, others less so. I wasn't offering a "suggested feature change" (which i would understand up/down voting that) - I asked a operational question. Should you be down voted for "assuming" or "inffering" something in the question that wasn't there?, I wouldn't do that - but that's me, not others.

Answer (score 8):

The post has answers with a positive score, so it won't be deleted.  If there were no answers, or none of the answers had a positive score, then it would have been deleted.

Comment: I would still have thought with the status as "closed" that further up/down votes of the question would be prevented. But, it was just how i thought the "closed" status was handled.

Comment: @Swodahs Closed means no more answers can be added. Voting is still allowed.

Comment: @Swodahs: Here is a deletion reference, from the FAQ: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244)

Answer (score 7):

Unless a post is deleted, votes are still possible. And, because your question has been answered, and those answers have positive votes, it won't be deleted automatically.

It's possible that a similar question was closed as a duplicate of yours and brought some attention to it or someone linked to the question somewhere... but it's also possible that someone simply found it by searching the tags or keywords in the question.

Regardless, don't worry about it too much. If it really bothers you, you can ask to have your account disassociated with the question but it will be on the site forever.

Comment: No, it's all good i guess. It was just an unexpected behavior to me, so i was asking for clarification. As you can see - someone attacked this question also.... i guess they love that downvote button.

Comment: @Swodahs Downvoting a bad post is not an attack.  It's someone providing valuable feedback on the quality of a post.

Comment: I suspect your downvotes here are a reaction to your apparent lack of research. Closing questions is a long-time feature and for anyone who has spent time here they know that "closing" only prevents the addition of new answers. Then there's also your non-standard grammar, which may also be attracting downvotes.

Comment: @AlE. If people are downvoting for non-standard grammar... on a site that attracts people from around the world... that's crap. Not everyone on the planet has perfect English.

Comment: @Servy Well for what its worth - This question here is not bad quality, its not griping, complaining nor does it lack appropriate content. It was a operational behavior that surprised me and it was seeking clarification if it was a bug or intentional. That's all - exactly the kind of question that's supposed to go here. It's not an "opinion" question. So, I find it funny its facing downvotes... but whatever i guess.

Comment: @Catija: I think there's a lot of leeway given to people for whom it's obvious English is not their first language. Not so much for people for whom it is but are apparently too lazy to write it decently.

Answer (score 2):

As Servy said, closed questions are able to be voted on, but cannot be answered. Locked posts on the other hand, can not be edited nor voted on (same for the answers to the locked posts).

With positive scores on some of the answers to your question, the question cannot be removed. See this post for more information: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)